# ggplot scale_fill_manual cannot assign colors in the right order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have the order of variables corresponding to a specific order of colors. So I explicitly assign the order of colors values to be corresponding to the break in scale_fill_manual(), as shown in the following scripts:

```
figure <- ggplot(df, aes(factor(groups), values, fill = parameter)) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 20, base_family = "Helvetica") + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  labs(x = xlabel_name, y = ylabel_name)

figure + scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"),
                           breaks = c('COLI_index', 'P_less_30k', 'employ_rat',  'NonWt_Pct', 'P_75k_200k', 'P_more_200')
)
```

Basically, I am expecting:

```
red:   COLI_index
blue:  P_less_30k
green: employ_rat
yellow:NonWt_Pct
brown: P_75k_200k
black: P_more_200
```

But in the figure I got, the order of the colors for each variables are:

```
    red:   COLI_index
    blue:  employ_rat 
    green: NonWt_Pct
    yellow:P_75k_200k
    brown: P_less_30k
    black: P_more_200
```

By the way, I am doing a grouped bar graph like this:
[image]

Any hints for which part is wrong?

The source data frame (df) is as following:

```
            groups  parameter   values
NonWt_Pct   Lowest  NonWt_Pct   33.5
employ_rat  Lowest  employ_rat  80.5
P_less_30k  Lowest  P_less_30k  15.0
P_75k_200k  Lowest  P_75k_200k  41.7
P_more_200  Lowest  P_more_200  12.1
COLI_index  Lowest  COLI_index  49.2
NonWt_Pct1  Second  NonWt_Pct   53.7
employ_rat1 Second  employ_rat  78.2
P_less_30k1 Second  P_less_30k  26.9
P_75k_200k1 Second  P_75k_200k  28.3
P_more_2001 Second  P_more_200  7.6
COLI_index1 Second  COLI_index  68.3
NonWt_Pct2  Third   NonWt_Pct   76.3
employ_rat2 Third   employ_rat  69.8
P_less_30k2 Third   P_less_30k  44.7
P_75k_200k2 Third   P_75k_200k  15.8
P_more_2002 Third   P_more_200  6.4
COLI_index2 Third   COLI_index  83.4
NonWt_Pct3  Highest NonWt_Pct   91.4
employ_rat3 Highest employ_rat  59.0
P_less_30k3 Highest P_less_30k  60.6
P_75k_200k3 Highest P_75k_200k  9.8
P_more_2003 Highest P_more_200  3.5
COLI_index3 Highest COLI_index  91.6
```

Comment: Could you share a minimal working example, or at least a part of the data with us?

Comment: Try naming the `values` vector. E.g.`values = c("COLI_index" = "red", "employ_rat" = "blue"...)`

Comment: ...which is stated in `?scale_fill_manual`, in the second example: "# It's recommended to use a named vector `cols <- c("8" = "red", "4" = "blue", "6" = "darkgreen", "10" = "orange")`".

Comment: Thank you @MikeH. that works!